# Why doesn't my custom font work for every widget instance added to the home screen?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, ipados

As you can see on the image below my custom font is not applied everywhere:

[image]

Only the top right is applied correctly. Not the others. This is screenshot from iPad Mini, iPadOS 16.3.1.

It seems that everything is done correctly.

This is my Font extension:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Font {
    static func openSansLight(withSize size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        return Font.custom("OpenSans-Light", size: size)
    }
}
```

and how it is used:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MonthTextView: View {
    private let text: String
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.openSansLight(withSize: 24))
    }
}
```

Of course my info.plist and source files:

[image]
[image]

Is there some limitation or something else that it is not displayed correctly? It happens only on iPadOS, on iOS it always works correctly even if I add 10 or more of the same widgets to the home view.

Comment: Widgets might be cached, try a completely different text color and see if the widget changes. Run the app target and run the widget target together on the device.